# error after converting code from Netlogo 5.3 to 6

Tags: netlogo

I am facing an error after I converted the code from Netlogo version 5.3 to 6. I cannot figure out what is the specific problem.

The code is as follows:

```
extensions [matrix distribution]

globals[

values-matrix
to setup-values 
 ] 

turtles-own 
[
 coalition-value
 amdc
 amep
 op
]


to setup-values
  generatePascalTriangle

   set values-matrix []

    let s-atual 0
    let CLs (list -1)
    set values-matrix lput CLs values-matrix

    file-close

   set values-matrix lput CLs values-matrix

  ask turtles 
[
    set coalition-value (getCoalitionValue (list (who + 1)))
  ]
end 

to-report getCoalitionValue [coalition]
report distribution:BM coalition op gamma amdc amep
end
```

I am getting the following error on the code **ask turtles**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Integer: 0
 at org.nlogo.core.Dump$$anonfun$dumpObject$1.applyOrElse(Dump.scala:18)
 at org.nlogo.core.Dump$$anonfun$dumpObject$1.applyOrElse(Dump.scala:12)
 at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:172)
 at org.nlogo.api.Dump$.logoObject(Dump.scala:34)
 at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceTraits$APIConformant.outputObject(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:214)
 at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceTraits$APIConformant.outputObject$(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:201)
 at org.nlogo.workspace.AbstractWorkspaceScala.outputObject(AbstractWorkspaceScala.scala:26)
 at org.nlogo.prim.etc._show.perform(_show.scala:13)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusive(Context.java:133)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ExclusiveJob.run(ExclusiveJob.scala:39)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.runExclusiveJob(Context.java:177)
 at org.nlogo.prim._asm_proceduresetupvalues_ask_10.perform(:1)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.Context.stepConcurrent(Context.java:107)
 at org.nlogo.nvm.ConcurrentJob.step(ConcurrentJob.scala:65)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.runPrimaryJobs(JobThread.scala:133)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.$anonfun$run$1(JobThread.scala:68)
 at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
 at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
 at org.nlogo.api.Exceptions$.handling(Exceptions.scala:41)
 at org.nlogo.job.JobThread.run(JobThread.scala:66)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is with the `distribution` extension.  I don't see that it is one distributed by NetLogo, so it may well not have been upgraded to NetLogo 6.1.  Indeed, if it is the same version you were using with NetLogo 5.3, I wouldn't expect it to work with 6.1  Do you get any error/information message when the model is loaded?

Comment: Hey Charles, the distribution extension has been updated for Netlogo 6.1 and there are no errors when the model is loaded. the error is encountered once I setup the model

Comment: If you comment out the `report distribution:BM coalition op gamma amdc amep`, do you still get the error?  If not, then either the arguments you pass to the extension are wrong, or the extension has an error. There is not much else going on in that `ask`.